# jQuery numeric input mask

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a simple integer numeric input mask without having to include an entire plugin like [Digital Bush's masked input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

Here's the code I've "repurposed" from another stackoverflow question:

```
$('input[name=Qty]').keyup(function() {
    var theEvent = evt || window.event;
    var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
    key = String.fromCharCode( key );
    var regex = '[0-9]'; /* Use |\. to include a decimal */
    if( !regex.test(key) ) {
     theEvent.returnValue = false;
     theEvent.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

The error is on the first line, where it doesn't know what evt is.
I think I need to use $(this) something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing `evt` in function parameter:

```
$('input[name=Qty]').keyup(function(evt) {
                                     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this as an alternative:

```
$('input[name=Qty]').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var myValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).val( myValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'') );
});
```