# enable only digits to enter into the Textbox using asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, regex

Update:

I can not use any plugin.

How do I enable only digits number to enter into the Textbox using asp.net using regexpression or jquery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery/2403051#2403051

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/ solved my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx).

It won't actually stop the user from entering something other than numbers, but it will validate it for you on the client and server side.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
                 ControlToValidate="MyTextBox"
                 ValidationExpression="\d+"
                 ErrorMessage="Please enter a number"
                 runat="server"/>
```

Comment: That expression will only allow one digit

Comment: @bdukes, whoops. Forgot the + sign. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Build one yourself http://snipt.net/GerryEng/jquery-making-textfield-only-accept-numeric-values

Comment: why can you not use any plugin? If you read the post though there is a link to how you can build the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full post about it: http://snipt.net/GerryEng/jquery-making-textfield-only-accept-numeric-values

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post that already answers the question:
[jquery-numeric-input-mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585403/jquery-numeric-input-mask) using regex.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your client-side behavior, you'll probably want a [`RegularExpressionValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) to verify the requirement on the server.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" 
                                ValidationExpression="\d+"                                    
                                ControlToValidate="NumberTextBox" 
                                ErrorMessage="Only numbers, please"
                                Text="*"
                                Display="Dynamic"
                                SetFocusOnError="true" />
```

If you have a jQuery plugin to more proactively restrict the input, you may also want to set [`EnableClientScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx) to `false`